# Erro: "invalid operands to binary expression ('char *' and 'char *')"

Tags: c, alocação, concatenação-de-string

Preciso criar uma *string* que contenha "Ao Sr.:\n" e o nome da pessoa em questão (`pessoa->nome`).

```
char* endereca(Pessoa* pessoa)
{
    if(pessoa->sexo == 'M')
    {
        char *msg;
        msg = (char*)malloc(7*sizeof(char) + sizeof(pessoa->nome));

        msg = "Ao Sr.:\n" + pessoa->nome; //Erro aqui
    }
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

Em C para concatenar *strings* é necessário o uso da função [`strcat()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat). Então ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
char* endereca(Pessoa* pessoa) {
    if (pessoa->sexo == 'M')  {
        char *msg = malloc(8 + sizeof(pessoa->nome));
        msg = strcat("Ao Sr.:\n", pessoa->nome);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Concat.c).

Coloquei 8 porque a *string* precisa de espaço para o seu terminador nulo. Se tiver alguma chance disso mudar seria melhor não deixar esse tamanho constante e sim verificar o tamanho da *string* com `sizeof`. Tirei o `sizeof` de `char` porque ele sempre é 1. Tirei o *cast* porque ele não faz algo útil, [pelo contrário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/353757/101).

Answer (score 2):

Você está tentanto somar dois ponteiros

```
msg = "Ao Sr.:\n" + pessoa->nome;
```

Esta é uma operação que não existe em C.

O que você provavelmente está tentando fazer é isso aqui:

```
static const char saudacoes[] = "Ao Sr.:\n";
char* msg = malloc(sizeof(saudacoes) + strlen(pessoa->nome));
strcpy(msg, saudacoes);
strcat(msg, pessoa->nome);
```