# Fazer casting do retorno de malloc(), calloc() e realloc() ou não?

Tags: c, cast, malloc

Segundo a discussão [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), em C não é recomendado ou correto fazer o casting do retorno da `malloc()`. Isto se aplica também às funções `calloc()` e `realloc()`?

Aproveitando, o correto é falar *cast*, *casting* ou os dois estão corretos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sobre a questão das palavras *cast* e *casting*, a especificação do C usa as duas palavras com significados diferentes.

Um rascunho da última especificação pode ser encontrado no link abaixo.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Neste documento, na seção 6.5.4 paragrafo 5, é estabelecido o seguinte:

> Preceding an expression by a parenthesized type name converts the value of the expression to the named type. This construction is called a cast. A cast that specifies no conversion has no effect on the type or value of an expression.

Já na seção 7.12.6.5, paragrafo 2, é dito:

> ...they are equivalent to calling the corresponding logb function and casting the returned value to type int.

Então concluo que aquele tipo entre parênteses que precede uma expressão é chamado de cast e o que ele está fazendo é um casting.

Em outras palavras, *cast* é essa construção da linguagem e *casting* é o que ela faz.

Comment: Obrigado, não sabe o quanto isso me atormentava kkk.
Obrigado também pela Referência, certamente será de grande valia.

Answer (score 6):

Sim, as funções tem as mesmas questões, até porque em essência elas retornam a mesma coisa, apenas o que é feito internamente é que diferente.

Não acho que língua seja nosso foco, mas sempre depende do contexto para definir qual é a palavra correta, ambas podem ser usadas no contexto da programação, cada uma em um contexto mais específica tem um significado gramatical diferente, mas nada que interfira diretamente no conceito da programação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Suspeitei, mas é sempre bom confirmar.
Obrigado.